# What is AbstractController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, production

In my Rails 3 production.log I see some errors like:

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'images' could not be found for ClientsController)

I don't notice anything going wrong. I searched for any call to 'images' and 'AbstractController' in my project but no clue.

What does this error mean and what does the AbstractController do?

Txs in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means you are missing a method `images` in your `ClientsController`? Or at least: tried to access that.

The `AbstractController` is a class inside Rails which serves as a base for every controller. Your `ApplicationController` derives from it.